# Updating android app on play store

Tags: android, android-sqlite

1. I developed an android app. Earlier it didn't have any database. Now I have added the database to it and uploaded the .apk on play store of the updated version.
   Now in further updates, I would only be updating its database. So, I want to ask that do I have to upload whole .apk as I did before or is there some other way to update?
2. Also, if I upload .apk as a whole with database in it, then when I update the app from play store, then does only database gets updated or the whole app?
   Ofcourse I will change the app version before uploading it on play store. But I want to know that if in that update only database changes, then will whole app be downloaded in the update or only the database part?

Comment: If the database can be changed by the user then I would install the database only once (or even better create it dynamically from code) because else it will be overwritten with each update. If the database format or data changes, then I would also do this by checking the database version and dynamically altering the strucutre.

Comment: you have to change version code for launch updated .apk file in your manifest file.

Comment: If you have not changed app then what the hell database is doing there now

Comment: my app is such that I only need to update the database and rest the code handles it itself on how and where to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you will have to upload the whole app and you should consider changing the version of the app from the Androidmanifest.xml

Comment: changing the version notifies the users who are using the app that a newer version is available and the whole app gets updated

Comment: Ofcourse I will change the app version before uploading it on play store. But I want to know that if in that update only database changes, then will whole app be downloaded in the update or only the database part?

Comment: Usually when you update the database, the application has to be updated as well, because of the new schema.